# use IF…THEN Sql query and return int and String

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have this Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Room] (
 [Id]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
 [Name]          NVARCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
 [Capacity]      TINYINT       NOT NULL,
 [CapacityOccupied] TINYINT       NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Room] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And Data in Table is:

.
[image]

I have use query for find status capacity, like this:

- **if room is full show full**
- **if room is empty show empty**
- **else show free capacity room**

i use this query but, i don't know how to show free capacity.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN (Capacity-CapacityOccupied)= Capacity
           THEN 'Empty'
        when (Capacity-CapacityOccupied)=0
            then 'Full'
   END as Salable, * 
FROM Room
```

And result is:

[image]

**Row 2,3,4 -> how to show free capacity?**
for example:
 - Empty
 - 3
 - 2
 - 1
 - Full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN (Capacity-CapacityOccupied)= Capacity
           THEN 'Empty'
        when (Capacity-CapacityOccupied)=0
            then 'Full'
        else cast((Capacity-CapacityOccupie) as varchar(10))
   END as Salable, * 
FROM Room
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
       WHEN (Capacity-CapacityOccupied)= Capacity
           THEN 'Empty'
       WHEN (Capacity-CapacityOccupied)=0
           THEN 'Full'
       ELSE 
           CAST((Capacity-CapacityOccupied) AS nvarchar(100))
   END AS Salable, * 
FROM Room
```

Comment: i can show free Capacity , not show free 
example 
full
2
3
4
free

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `Else`.  Also, the `Case` can be simplified:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CapacityOccupied = 0
           THEN 'Empty'
        when Capacity = CapacityOccupied
            then 'Full'
        Else Cast(Capacity - CapacityOccupied As Varchar (5))
   END as Salable, * 
FROM Room
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default to your CASE.

You are hitting your conditions but you need to cater for the condition when it is not completely full or completely empty.

**Edit**

Add this before the END

ELSE
       THEN 'Partially Occupied'

Comment: how to add default , i use else and use (Capacity-CapacityOccupied) but show error